# Should I place my app configurations in a JSON file or in a JS module?

Tags: javascript, configuration

I am building a JavaScript application where its behavior (some rules and logic) is configurable via JSON.

The configurations are deploy only with a new version of the app.

Currently my app, when initiated make few ajax requests to its JSON files.

I would like to know:

Should I include the configuration as a JavaScript module (so in a separate js file) and include it directly in the build, instead to have the app making and additional ajax requests? What is a common practice?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mainly depends on the complexity of your configuration. When using JSON, you cannot add comments (without tricks like `"_comment": "..."`) to your configuration. When using JavaScript you have the ability to add values which are not available in JSON (like functions) but also the risk of having a program as configuration instead of a declarative file.

I personally would propose using YAML or TOML for your configuration and compile it to JSON as part of your build process. This will get you a declarative configuration file with comments without and runtime overhead.